# How Can I Upgrade the Rails Version of My Rails Command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use rails version 5. I tried to use it, but my rails shows the version 4. Why?

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.3
$ gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-5.0.0
1 gem installed
$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.3
```

Comment: are you using rvm?

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your gemfile for existing apps

```
gem 'rails', '5.0.0'
```

then run in the project directory

```
bundle update rails
```

N.B. Rails 5 is dependent on **ruby >= 2.2.2**

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the Gemfile for now. I just tried to use the latest rails 5 on a new directory.

Comment: I want to use the latest version globally without Gemfile. Any tips?

Comment: you can just create a project with rails 4, then in the gemfile change the version. Or delete the rails previousd version and run `gem install rails --version=5.0.0`.

Comment: I don't want to delete any rails versions because I use them on other projects.

Comment: @gipcompany, in that case this is the only solution. create a project with the rails whatever version you're using. Then change in the `gemfile` and update `bundler`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to run `rbenv rehash` to update the rails command.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new Rails app with a specified version of Rails, you include that version as part of the command.

eg. `rails _5.0.0_ new my_app_name` will create a new Rails 5 app, if you have multiple versions of Rails installed.

Comment: Why does my default rails version always specify 4.2.3? How can I change it to version 5?

Comment: Likely you will need to rehash to tell rbenv about the new Rails version, as nikkypx's answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

you can install rails 5.0.0 using

`$ gem install rails -v 5.0.0`

It looks like now in your system you having two rails version as there is no way you can select default one through rbenv so I suggest you follow below step to install RVM and rails using RVM

**Update your package manager:**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

**Install Curl:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl
```

**Install RVM:**

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

**Install ruby with RVM**

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

For more information on how RVM works [click here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

Comment: Can the rbenv set the rails version? I think it can set a ruby version only though.

Comment: Yes you are right we can not set default version of rails using rbenv. Please accept my apologies. I have updated my answer.